# Structure of a periodic bijection on the set of bitstrings

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $S$ be the set of bitstrings of length $n$ i.e. strings of zeroes and ones. Let these bitstrings be ordered according to Hamming weight (i.e. number of ones in a string) and then by lexicographic order. Let $x\in S$, let $W(x)=w$ be the Hamming weight of $x$ and we now define a $f:S\to S$ to be such that $f(x)=y$ where $y$ is $\delta=\lfloor\frac{2^n}{n}\rfloor \text{ (mod }2^n)$ places to the right of $x$ in the ordering described above. This defines a bijection on $S$ to itself.

> 1. I am trying to find the structure of this bijection. Given $n$ and $w$ i.e. all those $x\in S$ s.t. $W(x)=w$, I am trying to find how many of these bitstrings $x$ are mapped to which weight classes under $f$.
> 2. Would the analysis be easier if we choose another $\delta$? I am allowed to change $\delta$ with the constraint that it needs to grow exponentially and be $o(2^n)$ where $o(\cdot)$ stands for little-O. So we can choose $\delta=\lfloor\frac{2^n}{n^2}\rfloor$ or something like that if it makes analysis easy.

My attempt: Let's say I want to look at the weight classes that bitstrings of $w=1$ are mapped to. Take the first $x$, in the ordering, s.t. $W(x)=1$. There are $\binom{n}{w}$ bitstrings for each $w$. To find $y$ s.t. $f(x)=y$ is complicated because I would need to find $k$ s.t.

$$\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{n}{i}<\frac{2^n}{n}<\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \binom{n}{i}$$

because that would mean $W(y)=k+1$. But as we know there are known [upper bounds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n) for $\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{n}{i}$ and not a precise equality which makes finding such $k$ hard. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Explicit example of $f$: Let $n=4$. If we order the strings first according to weight and then by lexicographic order, then we get this order:

$$0,1,2,4,8,3,5,6,9,10,12,7,11,13,14,15$$

where the above numbers are decimal values of bitstrings. Now $\lfloor\frac{2^n}{n}\rfloor = 4$. So $f(0)=8, f(8)=9, f(9)=11, f(11)=0, f(1)=3, f(3)=10, f(10)=13, f(13)=1, f(2)=5, f(5)=12, f(12)=14, f(14)=2, f(4)=6, f(6)=7, f(7)=15, f(15)=4$

Comment: Your $\delta$ is not in general an integer, so I am confused with your definition. Could you clarify and possibly give an explicit example of your bijection?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Yes, I was thinking $\lfloor \frac{2^n}{n} \rfloor$. Editing the question now.